# Configuration of NameVirtualHosts and IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, configuration, httpd.conf

so I have site1.com and 192.168.1.100

If I use the IP address Apache doesn't work for site1.com, if I use site1.com the IP address doesn't work. Thoughts?

Can I get both?

I need to access the IP and site1.com and have them point to different directories ( different projects )

Site1.com

```
#NameVirtualHost site1.com:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/www/site1.com/current/web
        ServerName site1.com
        ServerAlias site1.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site1.com/current/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

IP Address

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80>
#<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/www/ip/current/
        ServerName 192.168.1.100
        ServerAlias 192.168.1.100

        <Directory /home/www/ip/current/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ip_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ip_access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

UPDATED with Solution

Site1.com

```
#NameVirtualHost site1.com:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/www/site1.com/current/web
        ServerName site1.com
        ServerAlias site1.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site1.com/current/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

IP Address

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/www/ip/current/
        ServerName 192.168.1.100
        #ServerAlias 192.168.1.100

        <Directory /home/www/ip/current/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ip_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ip_access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your VirtualHost directives need to match the NameVirtualHost directive. 
So you must either use `*:80` in **both** VirtualHost **and** in Name VirtualHost, or you use `192.168.1.100:80` in all places.

You also do not need to set the same name as `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`. `ServerAlias` is meant for any additional names you want to assign to that virtualhost, in addition to `ServerName`.

Comment: so by using the IP address instead of *:80 in both configs, this should fix the issue?

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, yes.

Comment: hmm by adding this to both files NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80> I get this warning * Reloading web server config apache2                                                                                                                                                                            [Wed Jun 26 09:33:19 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Wed Jun 26 09:33:19 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts and both sites point to the IP site

Comment: FIrwst, it's really hard to read your log when you post it as a comment. Second, please post the relevant part of your new config - i.e. specifically the VirtualHost, ServerName, and NameVirtualHost directives. Post it as an edit to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Set a virtual host without ServerName as a catch-all virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/www/ip/current/
    <Directory>
    ...
```

Comment: doesn't work, still both point to only one project, need them to point to different code bases

Comment: adding the IP as the ServerName fixed this, +1 for leading me to the answer